# Reflectance values from WorldView-1 images?

Tags: qgis, data, remote-sensing, features

Most of the informations on WorldView images are related to the second and third version of the satellite. I own a WorldView-1 image (the black and white one) and I really need to find the reflectance values of the image pixels.

Is it possible even with single band (B/W) images?

Answer (score 2):

Correcting WorldView-1 is the same as correcting WorldView-2 & -3. The format of the metadata file is the same, so you can find the information where it always can be found (the metadata `IMD` file).

Combine the information in the metadata file with [this guide on how to calibrate WorldView-2](http://global.digitalglobe.com/sites/default/files/Radiometric_Use_of_WorldView-2_Imagery%20(1).pdf) while substituting all mentions of WorldView-2 with WorldView-1.